# compare two columns in two files "awk"

Tags: awk, merge, compare

I would like to compare two files for both $1,$2 column in awk. If same print all from second file and if  not same print all from first file.

1st file:

> a 1 2
>
> b 2 3
>
> c 3 4

2nd file:

> a 1 2 ko lo to
>
> b 2 3 to ho ro

result:

> a 1 2 ko lo to
>
> b 2 3 to ho ro
>
> c 3 4

So I would like to add lines from 1st file which are not match to second file.

I wrote:

```
 awk -v OFS="\t" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2=$3;next} {if (($1,$2) in a) print a[$1,$2,$3]; else print $0}'
```

but it is not work :-(
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '!a[$1,$2]++' file2 file1

a 1 2 ko lo to
b 2 3 to ho ro
c 3 4
```

this won't preserve the order though (it will print file2 contents first).  Another alternative is

```
$ awk    '{k=$1 FS $2} 
  NR==FNR {a[k]=$0; next} 
          {print (k in a?a[k]:$0)}' file2 file1
```